# jQuery prevent default, do something, stop propagation

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, event-handling

In my rails app, I'm trying to allow for users to "tag" blog posts on the form with categories by having users type in categories into a `text_field` that get separated when a user presses space bar (this works!) But when I go to submit the page, I want the tags grabbed and inserted back into the form so when the page submits the data can persist properly. The click listener is only getting executed after the page submits right now...

```
var ready;
ready = function() {



function removeItem(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().remove();
} 

$( "#article_article_tags" ).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32){
    var tag = $( "#article_article_tags" ).val(); 
    $("#article-tags").append("<p class='new-tag'>" + tag + "<a class='remove' href='#'> x</a></p>"); 
    $( "#article_article_tags" ).val("")
  }
});

$("#article-tags").on('click', '.remove', removeItem)


$('.btn article-submit-button').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $( "#article_article_tags" ).val($('.new-tag').text()); 
     event.stopPropagation(); 
  });


};


$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this line -  The click listener is only getting executed after the page submits right now...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the line `$('.btn article-submit-button').click(function(event) {` only gets executed when I hit "submit" and then right when the next page loads.

Comment: I am not clear with this line. So can please change words and say?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you look for the `submit` instead of `click` event, then change:

```
$('.btn article-submit-button').click(function(event) {
```

to:

```
$('#your_form').submit(function(event) {
```